# Paste text with newlines in it in Sql Server management studio 2008 'edit top 200 rows' window in a varchar(200) column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to manually edit a few records in the (SQL 2008) database.

I open up SSMS, rightclick on the table, choose '*edit top 200 rows*', locate the right record and column, paste my text (which is something like this, bold only for presentation):

> **Hi Michel,**
>
> **Congratulations!**
>
> **John**

And all that is stored is 'Hi Michel,'

all the lines but the first are 'lost'.

Is there a nice feature to paste the ENTIRE text in the field?

Comment: What is wrong with using an `INSERT` statement? :o)

Comment: because the user is not so familiair with Insert statements, but he CAN copy-paste text

Comment: I could have sworn you used to be able to do this in SQL Server 2005 with the (almost equivalent) Open Table interface. But my testing just now shows that this is not the case. It would quite useful during development for adding data before edit interface is built. Saying "Just use UPDATE SQL" is all well and good until you have quotes in your data :(

Comment: There's also a good bit more risk with a update/insert statement running away from you if you get the where clause off.  Damage you can do with the edit interface is throttled back a bit by how fast you can click thru rows :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this manually so i think your stuck with writing SQL.  For that as your editing records you could write it as an update statement.

String literals can span multiple lines, so you should be able to paste your updated in without reformatting it.

e.g.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET field_to_update = 'Hi Michel,

Congratulations!

John'
WHERE field = criteria_to_match
```

Comment: hmm, thanks for the answer (hoped to get an answer that i did something stupid and text could easily be pasted :))

Comment: Alas no, but if its really an issue for yourself then you could give Microsoft feeback on it here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback ...wether they listen is another matter! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You'd be better working in script. You can just write an update:

```
UPDATE <Table Name>
SET Column = 'Hi Michel,

Congratulations!

John'
WHERE <Key column conditions>
```

I don't believe there's any way to do this via the Edit pane.